# Super class reference to sub class in java

Tags: java, inheritance

I was trying to reference child class object using parent class. According to Complete Reference Java, parent class can refer to the child class but it can access only those fields that is already declared in parent class (complete reference java 8th edition, page no:166, second last paragraph).

According to complete reference 
It is important to understand that it is the type of the reference variable—not the type
of the object that it refers to—that determines what members can be accessed. That is,
when a reference to a subclass object is assigned to a superclass reference variable, you will
have access only to those parts of the object defined by the superclass. This is why plainbox
can’t access weight even when it refers to a BoxWeight object. If you think about it, this
makes sense, because the superclass has no knowledge of what a subclass adds to it. This is
why the last line of code in the preceding fragment is commented out. It is not possible for
a Box reference to access the weight field, because Box does not define one.

Now I am Using this example.
**Parent class
Box.java**

```
public class Box{
    int length;
    int breadth;
    int height;
    Box(int length, int breadth, int height){
        this.length = length;
        this.breadth = breadth;
        this.height = height;
    }
    public void getAll(){
        System.out.println("Length"+this.length+"\nBreadth"+this.breadth+"\nHeight"+this.height);
    }
}
```

**Child Class
BoxWeight.java**

```
public class BoxWeight extends Box{
    int weight;
    BoxWeight(int length, int breadth, int height, int weight){
        super(length,breadth,height);
        this.weight = weight;
    }   
    public void getAll(){
        System.out.println("Length"+this.length+"\nBreadth"+this.breadth+"\nHeight"+this.height+"\nWeight"+this.weight);
    }

    public int getWeight(){
        return this.weight;
    }
}
```

**Implementation Class**

```
public class Implementation{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Box simpleBox = new Box(10,10,23);
        BoxWeight boxWeight = new BoxWeight(10,10,10,30);
        System.out.println("box result");
        simpleBox.getAll();
        System.out.println("box weight result");
        boxWeight.getAll();
        simpleBox = new BoxWeight(10,10,10,560);
        System.out.println("Child class reference result");
        simpleBox.getAll();
        //System.out.println(simpleBox.getWeight());
    }
}
```

The Output is

```
box result
Length10
Breadth10
Height23
box weight result
Length10
Breadth10
Height10
Weight30
Child class reference result
Length10
Breadth10
Height10
Weight560
```

My Question is when I am referencing child class with parent object then why member variable of child class is accessible through parent class object. This should not happen according to complete reference java.

Comment: You should include the passage in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since `getAll()` is a public instance method, it is "virtual": the implementation in `BoxWeight` *overrides* the implementation in `Box`.

You have misunderstood the passage that you are reading. The `Box` class does not "refer" in any way to `BoxWeight` or `BoxWeight.weight` or `BoxWeight.getAll()`; rather, you're simply calling `simpleBox.getAll()`, and since `simpleBox` is an instance of `BoxWeight`, the relevant implementation of `getAll()` is the one from `BoxWeight`.

Comment: The confusion arises from simpleBox being *declared* as holding a Box reference but this permits storing simpleBox references. The selection of the method to call is done at runtime, depending on the type of the *object the reference atually points to*.

Answer (score 0):

Where does the member variable of child class is accessed through parent class object in the above example ???

After assigning the `BoxWeight`object to `simpleBox` (the  Box class reference variable), `simpleBox`only accessed a method `getAll()`. And the `getAll()` method called is of the class `BoxWeight`. It happened because, the `getAll()` method is there in both super class `Box` and subcalss `BoxWeight`, with same signature, which is criteria for method overriding. So the subclass (BoxWeight ) object , `simpleBox`overrides the `getAll()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your support. Actually I got the answer, this thing is happening due to dynamic method dispatch.
Thanks